# python how to form list to comma separated string for with correct quote for sql where in statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

The below logic is used to convert so that list of strings such that each string is within quotes and comma separated

```
>>> record_hash
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
>>> t="'"+"','".join(record_hash)+"'"
>>> t
"'AAA','BBB','CCC'"
>>>
```

This logic is passed to below logic to form the SQL statement to form the `where column in` condition

```
 def selectAllPackageType(record_hash, severity):
        t="'"+"','".join(record_hash[])+"'"
        joined_string = ', '.join(['"{}"'.format(value) for value in record_hash])
        sql = 'select package_type from slack_jira where severity = ? and  record_hash in (?)'
        print(sql)
        conn = getSQLConnection();
        package_type = []
        conn.set_trace_callback(print)
        if conn is not None:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql,(severity,t))
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in records:
                package_type.append(row['package_type'])
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
        else:
            print("Error! cannot perform selectByPackageType.")
        return package_type
```

The `conn.set_trace_callback(print)` prints this value which is causing to fail the fetch the record as it contains one single record

```
select package_type from slack_jira where severity = 'MEDIUM' and  record_hash in ('''AAAAA'',''CCCC''');
```

what is needed is to form the correct SQL statement to be created with proper escape for `where column in (?)`

```
select package_type from slack_jira where severity = 'MEDIUM' and  record_hash in ('AAAAA','CCCC');
```

Comment: The empty square brackets in `t="'"+"','".join(record_hash[])+"'"` should be giving you a `SyntaxError`. You also never use `joined_string`? Beyond that, it might help if you printed `t` and `record_hash` just to confirm that they contain what you think they should.

Comment: try `t=",".join(record_hash)`

Comment: hi @TinNguyen it prints this  select package_type from slack_jira where severity = 'MEDIUM' and  record_hash in ('AAA,BBB')

Comment: okay then there is no way around that. You need to use the `?` placeholder. You cannot insert a dynamic amount of variables in there. The `?` is sanitized and only accepts "one string value". --- as in your sql statement needs to have multiple `?` and then you just unpack `*record_hash`

Comment: Try to change `sql` to have ending `... record_hash in ?` i.e. replace `(?)` with `?` plus change `t` to be `t = tuple(record_hash)`.

Comment: @anish Have you tried my last comment above?

Comment: Hey @Arty select distinct package_type from slack_jira where severity = ? and  record_hash in ?  it thorws out the error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Comment: Hi @Arty 
def selectAllPackageType(record_hash, severity):
    t = tuple(record_hash)
    sql = "select distinct package_type from slack_jira where severity = ? and  record_hash in ?"

Comment: @anish Try `t=tuple(record_hash)` and `sql = 'select package_type from slack_jira where severity = ? and  record_hash in %s' % t`.

Comment: @anish Also I forgot, for comment above to work you need also to change line `cursor.execute(sql,(severity,))`, i.e. remove `t`.

Comment: This last solution above is a hack, but should work :) Also it doesn't check `record_hash` to contain some malicious code, but if you trust its value and you don't have Hackers there then solution above is alright.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, this is working

`result_set = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM slack_jira WHERE severity='MEDIUM' and id IN (%s)" % ','.join('?'*len(record_hash)), record_hash)`

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/test.db')
>>> conn.set_trace_callback(print)
>>> record_hash=['A','B']
>>> result_set = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM slack_jira WHERE severity='MEDIUM' and id IN (%s)" % ','.join('?'*len(record_hash)), record_hash)
SELECT * FROM slack_jira WHERE severity='MEDIUM' and id IN ('A','B')
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution!